# How to pass objects through IBAction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, ibaction

test is a NSString which is declared and called in my ViewController viewDidLoad as:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *test = [[NSString alloc]init];
    test = @"This is a Test";
}
```

However, if try to use test in a IBAction, nothing is passed and I get NULL instead of the test String.

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", test];
    [self.simpleLabel setText:message];
    [self.simpleTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Is `test` also an ivar or property? If so, get rid of the line `NSString *test = [[NSString alloc]init];` from `viewDidLoad`. That's creating a local variable named `test` and it hides the ivar named `test`.

Comment: Tnxs, this answered my question! However, since this simple example originated from a more complex one where instead of a string I am using a custom class with a string name as one of its properties, if I do not alloc/init it in viewDidLoad I cannot work with it; and by doing that it is not visible in the IBAction although it is added in the header file...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a member variable like `NSString *test` into your .h file, and `test` will be accessible by any method in your class once you've done that.

Example:

```
@interface MyClass : UIViewController {
   NSString *test;
}

@end
```

And to access:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
   test = @"test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple things.

1. You don't need to say `alloc/init` for an `NSString`, you can simply say `someString = @"myString";`
2. You should create a property where you can hold onto your string for future use, so for example

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *someString;`

then in `viewDidLoad`

`self.someString = @"Hello World";`

Finally, in your `IBAction` you can say:

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello, %@", self.someString];
    [self.simpleLabel setText:message];
    [self.simpleTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```